# Switching speakers between multiple audio sources

Tags: audio, switches, connector

I have a xbox and a PC, and I want to connect them both to the same speaker set (Logitech 2.1).

Guessing I need a switch and found [this one](http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=R1043241).

But I have no clue if it's any good for audio (regarding the contact rating). Could anyone comment if this is a good switch? What do I need to consider?

Comment: Please clarify "connect them both." Are you planning to hear both the Xbox and PC output at the same time from a single speaker set?

Comment: No, thats why I need to know what kind of switch fits best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio outputs accepting *stereo* [3.5mm TRS connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#Tiny_telephone) will have 2 separate channels - the [tip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#Tip-ring-sleeve_terminology) for left signal channel and the ring for right channel. Thus on a minimum, you need a [dual pole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology) (two channels) double throw (two devices) switch to toggle between the Xbox and PC. For the safety of the circuits in the devices, one output device must be disconnected first from the speaker before the other will be connected. To do that you need to specify a "break before make"/BBM switch. The sleeves of both devices will share the same ground going to the speakers.

The switch that you found is a DPDT (dual pole double throw) and from its [datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/01a6/0900766b801a6340.pdf) (model STA 206 P) has an on-off-on contact pattern or 3 positions (device one, none, device two) which satisfies the BBM requirement. You can use that switch and ignore contact ratings - the current of the audio signal is magnitudes smaller than the typical capacity of miniature toggle switches.